# Changing a nested list using a tuple as a path

Tags: python, list

I have some data from another program (Grasshopper) that is roughly equivalent to an ordered dict and can be converted into the form

```
[ (0,0,0):[info], (0,0,1):info, (0,1,0):info ]
```

I can convert this into a list of tuples and a list of info but my end goal is to recreate the structure as a nested list i.e.

```
[[[info, info], [info]]]
```

The info can be of any type so could be a list or a float etc.

The problem is that the tuples can be of arbitrary length so I do not know in advance how many dimensions I will have in the nested list. This means I cannot use the list[x][y] method and I haven't managed to get a recursive function to assign an immutable type (the info).

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: the real question is why do you want to do this? it sounds like the XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Fair point, I could possibly avoid doing this. On the other hand, having a simple but workable conversion would simplify the code and avoid repetition which is always nice!

Comment: exactly what repetition is it avoiding? my hunch is that there's a better way to do this

Comment: The repetition is that every piece of information I receive from Grasshopper will be in this format so its not a one-off problem!

Comment: right, no, gotcha. so why not just keep it that way? i.e. `{(0,0,0):[info], (0,0,1):info, (0,1,0):info}`?

Comment: in other words, my question is what benefit does a nested list confer?

Comment: also, it seems like your resulting data structure should actually be `[[[[info], info], [info]]]`

Comment: The reason was that it will be compared/combined with other information that shares that data structure (I am using Grasshopper to perform some calculations as part of a larger project). On the other hand, you may be right - maybe it is easier to just perform the association on the fly using the data structure I am given.

Answer (score 0):

why not just do something with a `defaultdict` and `list`?

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for gds in grasshopper_data_structs:
    for k, v in gds.items():
       d[k].append(v)
```